# Error: There was an error deploying functions Error ID: beaf8772

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I'm trying using Firebase Functions in my web project, just after I installed functions I created a simply function and put it in index.js and deployed `firebase deploy --only functions`  and then I got the errors attached:

errors after deploy: https://justpaste.it/2915k

I tried deleting all files from firebase installation and reinstalling them

deleting node_modules directory from Functions and root directory and reinstalling them using `npm install`

creating a new project in Firebase and connect it to the directory project

clearing cache using `npm cache clean --force` in root directory

functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Create an HTTP function that responds with "Hello, Firebase!"
exports.helloFirebase = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello, Firebase!');
});
```

functions/package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

root (project directory)/package.json

```
{
  "name": "coupon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

functions/package-lock.json : https://justpaste.it/525f4
root (project directory)/package-lock.json : https://justpaste.it/d7mq8

firebase functions:log: https://justpaste.it/c4jpd